# How do you correctly work with NSStreams (no blocking, read to the end of the data, and message retrying)?

Tags: ios, swift, nsstream

I'm trying to work with `NSInputStream` and `NSOutputStream` but it's causing a lot of pain.

I have two devices that communicate Json. Some of the data can be very long so `NSOutputStreamsends` splits it up in multiple packets.

I need receiving not to block on the main thread and able to read all the needed json packets before trying to parse it. Then continue reading the rest json data packets.

I need sending not to block on the main thread and able to finish sending the data if the first batch failed to send. Then continue sending the rest of the json data.

I'm using swift but can also use objective c.

Here is the code so far. My basic stream helper class:

```
public class StreamHelper : NSObject, NSStreamDelegate {
    static let DATA_BYTE_LENGTH = 4;

    public static func writeToOutputStream(text: String!, outputStream:NSOutputStream!) -> Int!{
        let encodedDataArray = [UInt8](text.utf8)

        var count: Int = encodedDataArray.count.littleEndian
        //convert int to pointer, which is required for the write method.
        withUnsafePointer(&count) { (pointer: UnsafePointer<Int>) -> Void in
            outputStream.write(UnsafePointer<UInt8>(pointer), maxLength: DATA_BYTE_LENGTH)
        }
        let bytesWritten = outputStream.write(encodedDataArray, maxLength: encodedDataArray.count)
        return bytesWritten;
    }

    public static func readFromInputStream(inputStream: NSInputStream!) -> String!{
        var buffer = [UInt8](count: 4096, repeatedValue: 0)
        var text = ""

        while (inputStream.hasBytesAvailable){
            let len = inputStream!.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
            if(len > 0){
                if let output = NSString(bytes: &buffer, length: buffer.count, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String{
                    if (!output.isEmpty){
                        text += output
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return text
    }
}
```

Core code:

```
public func stream(aStream: NSStream, handleEvent eventCode: NSStreamEvent) {
    print("Reading from stream... ")
    switch (eventCode){
        case NSStreamEvent.ErrorOccurred:
            print("ErrorOccurred")
            break
        case NSStreamEvent.None:
            print("None")
            break
        case NSStreamEvent.EndEncountered:
            print("EndEncountered")
            if((aStream == inputStream) && inputStream!.hasBytesAvailable){
                // If all data hasn't been read, fall through to the "has bytes" event
            } else{
                break
            }
        case NSStreamEvent.HasBytesAvailable:
            print("HasBytesAvaible")
            let methodJson = StreamHelper.readFromInputStream(inputStream!)
            if(!methodJson.isEmpty){
                let cMethodJson = methodJson.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
                let returnedJsonString = String.fromCString(callMethod(cMethodJson))
                StreamHelper.writeToOutputStream(returnedJsonString, outputStream: outputStream!)
            }
            break
        case NSStreamEvent.OpenCompleted:
            print("OpenCompleted")
            break
        case NSStreamEvent.HasSpaceAvailable:
            print("HasSpaceAvailable")

            if(aStream == outputStream){
            }
            break
        default:
            break
    }
}
```

Some setup code:

```
func connectToService(service: NSNetService!){

service.getInputStream(&inputStream, outputStream: &outputStream)

inputStream!.delegate = self
outputStream!.delegate = self

inputStream!.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
outputStream!.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
inputStream!.open()
outputStream!.open()
}
```

How does one work with NSStreams correctly or is there a better solution than using NSStreams?

Comment: why NSStreams? Would sockets or running small HTTP server with bonjour be an option?

Comment: I am using Bonjour and sockets to make the connection. Is there something else than NSStreams I should be using to set/get the data?

Comment: why at all? json doesnt seem to be a good format for streaming to me.

Comment: All the communication is done with Json. That bit can't be changed.

Comment: I am not doubting json. I am doubting to use nsstream.

Comment: I'm doubting NSStream too. I added some setup code above. If you can think of another way to do it, I'm all ears.

Comment: As i said: sockets or a http server, running in your app.

Comment: I'm already using Bonjour which uses sockets. Yes http server could be done, but that seems odd for a mobile application. That will probably be a large job, so maybe I could look at that if all else fails. Thanks.

Comment: Why should it be a big job. U don't need to install Apache. I used this approach in several app – flawlessly.

Comment: Oh good to hear.
Just that I have to coordinate with a 3rd party which is building the hardware device which we communicate with our application.

Comment: I would use [GCDAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket)or similar or a http server as [swifter](https://github.com/glock45/swifter)

Comment: @vikingosegundo GCDAsyncSocket seems to have exactly what I need. Put that as an answer and I'll give you the award. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably working too hard here. `NSStreamDelegate` was designed before GCD, when the majority of Cocoa work was done on a single thread. While there are still reasons to use it in some cases, in most cases GCD and synchronous methods will make it much easier. For example, to read you'd do something like this:

```
import Foundation

enum StreamError: ErrorType {
    case Error(error: NSError?, partialData: [UInt8])
}

func readStream(inputStream: NSInputStream) throws -> [UInt8] {
    let bufferSize = 1024
    var buffer = [UInt8](count: bufferSize, repeatedValue: 0)
    var data: [UInt8] = []

    while true {
        let count = inputStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.capacity)

        guard count >= 0 else {
            inputStream.close()
            throw StreamError.Error(error: inputStream.streamError, partialData: data)
        }

        guard count != 0 else {
            inputStream.close()
            return data
        }

        data.appendContentsOf(buffer.prefix(count))
    }
}

let textPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("text.txt", ofType: nil)!
let inputStream = NSInputStream(fileAtPath: textPath)!
inputStream.open()
do {
    let data = try readStream(inputStream)
    print(data)
} catch let err {
    print("ERROR: \(err)")
}
```

This will block the current queue, sure. So don't run it on the main queue. Put the `do` block into a `dispatch_async`. If you later need the data on the main queue, `dispatch_async` it back, just like any other background process.

Comment: I would still need NSStreamDelegate to check when there is data on the socket right? Yes using dispatch_async would help with the blocking thanks. But still stuck on handling the json if the packets get split up. Handling a queue of json to send out and make sure all the data gets sent (checking bytesWritten).

Comment: The call to `read` blocks until the first byte arrives, so you don't need a delegate to wait for that. The call to `write` returns how many bytes were written, which is the information you need to construct the retry. If possible, I would try to think only of "data" at this level, and not treat it as JSON. Make sure you can send and receive arbitrary bytes reliably. Then at the next level up worry about converting it into JSON messages, and above that into data structures.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of working with NSStreams, I would work with sending over sockets directly.
There are wrappers to make this task easier, most notably GCDAsyncSocket.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other answers I came up with this, which works in Swift 4.2.

```
public enum StreamError: Error {
    case Error(error: Error?, partialData: [UInt8])
}

extension InputStream {

    public func readData(bufferSize: Int = 1024) throws -> Data {
        var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: bufferSize)
        var data: [UInt8] = []

        open()

        while true {
            let count = read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.capacity)

            guard count >= 0 else {
                close()
                throw StreamError.Error(error: streamError, partialData: data)
            }

            guard count != 0 else {
                close()
                return Data(bytes: data)
            }

            data.append(contentsOf: (buffer.prefix(count)))
        }

    }
}
```